# phpPgAdmin - Login Fail - Virtual Class--cannot instantiate

Tags: phppgadmin

So I followed every step of the YouTube video on getting phpPgAdmin setup with XAMPP.

After I access localhost/phppgadmin using the credentials..

1. USERNAME: postgres
2. password: the password I created during setup..

I click login and I get ..

> Virtual Class -- cannot instantiate

Having a hard time figuring this out, can someone please help me.
Thank you

Comment: have you found the solution?

Comment: seems like this issue is already address: https://github.com/phppgadmin/phppgadmin/pull/118

Answer (score 18):

I searched for the string "Virtual Class -- cannot instantiate" within all files in the folder and found it in the file "adodb.inc.php" (in my version it is on line 432):

```php
  /**
   * Constructor
   */
  function __construct()            
  {
    die('Virtual Class -- cannot instantiate');
  }
```

So I commented the line and phpPgAdmin started working again.

PS: it doesn't seem like the most appropriate way to fix the problem, but I needed it working soon

Comment: In Arch Linux the file is in the `/usr/share/webapps/phppgadmin/libraries/adodb/adodb.inc.php` path.

Comment: after comment this line getting this errs "Error Loading all_db.php?action=tree&subject=server&server=%3A5432%3Aallow (200: OK)"

Answer (score 1):

For people who are having problems in 2023 . @hericklr answer doenst is appropriate .

This is related with php ^8.0 versions !

Unfortunately for i see in the github phppgadmin page , the owner doesnt apply a update for long time .

So i made a fork updated : https://github.com/EdvaldoAFilho/pgAdmin

Just download and extract to : **/usr/share/phppgadmin**

*(/usr/share/phppgadmin/[files])*

Hope it works !